# Session cookie attachment after cross domain REST request

Tags: ajax, session, cookies, session-cookies

After sending a cross domain from domain X to domain Y POST AJAX request, and subsequent redirection to Y, what can I do to retain the session cookie from the original POST request to the redirection?

To elaborate on the situation, I am working on a pre-existing chat application.  There is a POST request to authenticate and create a new user and tie the user to the HTTPsession.  The browser is then redirected to a new page.  Nothing fancy on the redirect, it could even be replaced by the visitor typing in the URL.

This worked fine when the two are in the same domain, but externalization of the entry point has run into the problem, where the POST request and the subsequent redirect have different sessions attached.